# Deferring promises in Karma test of angular ngResources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

Currently I'm using ngResource for my RESTful API calls, and I'm using KARMA & jasmine to do my unit and integration tests. 
Inside one Controller i have a function that expects promise to be finished:

```
var elem = new Element() // calling a ngResource Factory    

elem.$save().then(function () {
    $scope.elem.push(elem);
});
```

In my karma tests, i test if the list is empty, that call the function above and check if the `$scope.elem` Array does have the new created element. But since its a promise, KARMA test does not solve this. I tried to use $rootScope.apply(), but the $httpBackend expects that i define lots of calls, that are expected. But i just want to simulate the call.

Is there any elegant solution for that?

Comment: Are you using jasmine? What kind of unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: Yes, im using jasmine. Added to the description

Answer (score 0):

There is not elegant solution for this. Main purpose of testing is prepare "isolated" ecosystem for test. If you want to test ajax call , they must return something. You cant test and just tell "skip this promise and act as like it was success".

When you need to resolve any promise, i am using this.

```
  $httpBackend.flush();
  $rootScope.$apply();
```

This will call $httpBackend, and ofcourse it will expecting call. You have no choice

1.) Mock all backend calls (this is taken from my test)

```
 identityBackend = $httpBackend.when("GET", AppConfig.API_IDENTITY_ENDPOINT + "/me",null,function(headers)
        {
            return headers.Authorization !== undefined;
        }).respond(200, fakeAuthUser);
```

So it will respond with http 200 with fake json on request host/me , when authorization token inside headers is not undefined.

2.) Second choice, create mockable backend inside nodejs/express and mock all requests with jsons. Before starting jasmine test , you will also start this "fake" backend server.